# Is it possible to get the Hotspot version from the source code itself?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

A lot of times I find some modified Hotspot implementations on Github and would like to compare the code to the original Hotspot version to see which code has been added/removed. This is difficult if I don't know the version of Hotspot the project is built on. I cannot find the original Hotspot code in the commit history either. GIT diff doesn't really work if I don't know the version exactly because it gives a lot of changes (slightly different code for different versions).

I tried looking in the source code, but cannot find the build number there and what I found on the internet is that the build number is given during the build process, it is not present in the source code. Is that right?
Also, if the version cannot be found, is there another approach to find what are the additions compared to the original Hotspot source code?

Comment: `.hgtags` in the repository root may help, unless it was deleted. Otherwise use binary search among commits, looking if they are present in the cloned repo or not. `grep -rh "@bug"|sort` will reduce the search by showing bugs that has been definitely fixed.